# AWS Glue Crawler different data types

Tags: aws-glue

I'm under the impression that when a crawler finds a discrepancy in a data type, it will produce a result similar to this:

```
|-- itemcount: choice
|    |-- int
|    |-- long
```

My crawler is doing this:

```
|-- itemcount: struct
|    |-- int: int
|    |-- long: long
```

Why?  I can't find any documentation around this